# AlarmManager only works for AM hours

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to know, why my alarmanager only works when I setup the hour in `"AM"` in the timepicker. Even if it is 7:00PM (and so it is on the phone), it will not work if I set the alarm to PM as it should be for that time, but it will work if I set the alarm for the `"AM"` hour.

As you can see, all `"AM"` hours works well, but when i try to setup the alarm for `"PM"` it does not work at all.

```
Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

Intent alarm_on = new Intent(this, MainTaskAlarmReciever.class);

alarm_on.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarm_on, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`

> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

```
Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

Intent alarm_on = new Intent(this, MainTaskAlarmReciever.class);

alarm_on.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarm_on, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Hello sir, now the alarm sound for PM too, however, if i set a AM hour it triggers the alarm too. Can you help me about how can i prevent this to happen? Thank you

Comment: Do you have multiple alarms scheduled? Use .cancel() to clear all of your alarms - or reboot your device to clear the pending intents from being delivered. I don't entirely understand if this doesn't resolve your woes. HOUR_OF_DAY is either 7 or 19

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess that in order to prevent the alarm to sound in previous hours for that day, i have to check if the hour the user is setting has already past.

Answer (score -1):

@jonnv , this is my alarm sample app, just refer it .
https://github.com/ananth10/WakeUp-Alarm-Sample